# calling opendir(3) on a textfile not a directory

Tags: c

What happens if you call `opendir(argv[i])` and `argv[i]` is the name of a `textfile`, not a `directory`?

Comment: "what happens...." you could always try it and see

Comment: @TerryG: but if the behavior is unspecified/undefined, that's not always reliable (thankfully, in this case, it's well defined, so that would be a good educational test to try).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From `man opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir):

> **Return Value**
>   The `opendir()` and `fdopendir()` functions return a pointer to the directory stream. On error, `NULL` is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately.

In this case, `errno` would be `ENOTDIR`: name is not a directory.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to know if argv[i] is a filename then without using opendir?

Comment: Look at [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat), there's a `S_ISREG`   macro you can use on the response to check if its a regular file or not.

Comment: might it be easier to first try to open it as a file with fopen, and then as a directory?

Comment: @Apollo: You can do whatever you want. You could do that. Personally, I might prefer `stat`, because it's 1 function call that tells you everything. Now, if you want to open the file/directory, then sure, you can just try `fopen`/`opendir` and skip the `stat` call, but you haven't said whether or not you want to actually *open* the path.

Comment: thanks, good point. If it's a file I don't want to open it, so I suppose stat would be better practice.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) says what will happen:

> The opendir() and fdopendir() functions return a pointer to the
>   directory stream. **On error, NULL is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately.**

Answer (score 0):

[POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>   Upon successful completion, these functions shall return a pointer to an object of type DIR. Otherwise, these functions shall return a null pointer and set errno to indicate the error.
>
> [...]
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> The opendir() function may fail if:
>
> [...]
>
> [ENOTDIR]
>   A component of dirname names an existing file that is neither a directory nor a symbolic link to a directory.

So, it returns `NULL`, and sets `errno` to `ENOTDIR`.